How to add prometheus support in my Bitcoin full node application in Rust
How can I implement prometheus client support in Rust in my bitcoin full node application, I was having trouble finding leads. A theoritical explanation on what I have to do, or some code snippets would help me a lot, to go in the right direction.

Bitcoin Core is written in C++. If you want to add Prometheus support to it, you'll need to propose a change to its source code.
